# Is it possible to block outgoing connections using .htaccess file?

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess

I don't have access to iptables, only .htaccess file.

So, is it possible to block **outgoing** connections to specific IP addresses using .htaccess file only?

For example, I have an obfuscated PHP script with annoying update notifications.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you talking of blocking outgoing connections from a server-side language like PHP for example?

Comment: Nope, htaccess won't help. However I think you can redirect those specific IP addresses to somewhere else in /etc/hosts file? Kind of restricting to access those IPs from the entire system. DNS will be overwritten and those IPs will be redirected to new IP. EDIT: If you don't have firewall access, then you likely also don't have /etc/hosts access... :(